# How to use special SSH key for BitBucket and GitHub to push/pull?

Tags: git, mercurial, ssh, github, bitbucket

I had Ubuntu 10.04 and recently upgraded to 11.10. Additional SSH keys stopped working. I have keys `bitbucket` and `github`, which I have in the websites. How can I tell SSH to use one particular key for Bitbucket and another for GitHub?

So, I have a config:

```
Host bitbucket
HostName 207.223.240.182
User hg
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bitbucket
```

When I call `ssh bitbucket`, ssh successfully logs in with the key and gets kicked out. But when I try `hg pull`, I see "no response from remote hg." and the passphrase is not asked.

What can be done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the little explanation on why the config posted in the question doesn't work but your answer does :

When you call `ssh bitbucket`, ssh looks in your config file for a host named `bitbucket` which is defined with the `Host` keyword. Then, using the `HostName` keyword, you can define the **real** hostname to use. In your case, you're defining `bitbucket` as an alias for the IP 207.233.240.182 which I assume is the one for `bitbucket.org`

It wasn't working for your mercurial commands because the remote server is probably defined as `bitbucket.org` and not the alias `bitbucket`. After you changed the config file to the one proposed in your answer, ssh can effectively match the remote server to the host name and everything is fine !

FYI, you can also use wildcard for the pattern matching, for example :

```
Host bitbucket.*
    HostName 207.223.240.182
    User hg
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bitbucket
```

Would also work, because when looking at the config, SSH will replace the * with anything else.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try hard enough! The key is there now. Solution was to add `.org` to host:

```
Host bitbucket.org
User hg
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bitbucket2
```

Comment: If you have many keys, consider adding the IdentitiesOnly yes option.