# BitBucket error when trying to push on OSX

Tags: macos, ssh, mercurial, bitbucket

Problem:

```
silver@calypso:~/Projects/scool% hg push -v  
pushing to ssh://sssilver@bitbucket.org/sssilver/scool
running ssh sssilver@bitbucket.org 'hg -R sssilver/scool serve --stdio'
remote: Permission denied (publickey).
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!
```

I do have my public key uploaded into my BitBucket account.

Permissions on my keys seem to be fine:

```
silver@calypso:~/Projects/scool% ls -al ~/.ssh
total 40
drwx------   6 silver  staff   204 Mar 10 12:10 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 59 silver  staff  2006 Apr  6 03:30 ..
-rw-------   1 silver  staff  1766 Feb  9 18:10 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--   1 silver  staff   400 Feb  9 18:10 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--   1 silver  staff  3560 Apr  6 03:15 known_hosts
```

The identity appears to be properly loaded:

```
silver@calypso:~/Projects/scool% ssh-add -l
2048 20:3b:9b:9f:b0:72:8f:a0:cd:40:6f:44:f9:28:86:5b /Users/silver/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
```

I seem to be able to even properly log into the bitbucket.org SSH server:

```
silver@calypso:~/Projects/scool% ssh -T hg@bitbucket.org  
logged in as sssilver.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
```

And my ssh-agent indeed seems to be running:

```
silver@calypso:~/Projects/scool% ps -e |grep ssh-agent
 2866 ??         0:00.10 /usr/bin/ssh-agent -l
 2919 ??         0:00.04 ssh-agent
 2962 ttys000    0:00.00 grep ssh-agent
```

Note that my system is OSX Maverick, however I haven't tried doing this on other systems/devices.

What could be causing this strange behavior?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171613/how-to-use-special-ssh-key-for-bitbucket-and-github-to-push-pull for agent-less proper usage

Comment: Not sure how that helps me. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: You are pushing to `ssh://sssilver@bitbucket.org/sssilver/scool` rather than `ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/sssilver/scool`. Your shell login attempt uses the latter, which is probably why it worked.